# How to specify specific auth.uid metadata in firebase CRUD operations

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I've gone through documentation, and I'm sure I'm missing something. Here is my use-case:

I have a firebase storage bucket with a `submissions` folder. In it, people with authenticated, email-validated sessions can upload mp3 files with a custom metadata tag `userUID` which contains their UID.

Here are the security rules that I have in Firebase Storage (which works completely in the rules playground). In dev, I get a 403 unauthorized error.

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{submissions}/{song} {
        allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.token.email_verified == true;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.token.email_verified == true && request.resource.metadata.userUID == request.auth.uid && request.resource.contentType == 'audio/mpeg';
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the upload function (the data part is correct. If there's an issue, it's in the storage invocation):

```
async function uploadSongs() {
    if (!currentUser || !songs.length) {
      return
    }
    // empty/null check good
    setUploading(true)
    const metadata = {
      contentType: 'audio/mpeg',
      userUID: currentUser.uid,
      uploaded_by: currentUser.email
    }
    Promise.all(songs.map(song => {
      // This is where we upload each file
      const uploadTask = 
      storage.ref().child('submissions').child(song.file.name).put(song.data, metadata)
      uploadTask.on("state_changed",
        snapshot => {
          const progress = ((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100)
          if (snapshot.state === "running") {
            console.log("Progress: ", progress)
          }
        },
        error => {
          console.log("Error: ", error)
          setUploading(false)
          resetProgress()
        },
        async () => {
          // Where we get the URL of the file
          const downloadURL = await uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()
          db.collection('artists').doc(currentUser.uid).get()
            .then(doc => {
              const data = doc.data()

          })
        }
      )
      })
    )
    .then(() => {
      // This is when all files have finished uploading - We add the urls to the user document for safe tracking
      
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // This is where any errors are caught
      setSongProgress(0)
      setTotalProgress(0)
    })
  }
```

Please let me know if I missed anything, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh my gosh. I forgot to put the error. Haha it's a 403 error, but the rules pass in the playground.

Comment: Note that we have no way to know what `currentUser` is in your code. I recommend reading (and logging) the current user directly from Firebase when trying to reproduce the problem. So `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid`. Or you can check all values that your security rules enforce in the code too, so: 1) is there a current User, 2) is their email address verified, 3) only then start uploading the file.

Comment: As I've said, all of the data is coming through. current User is the user auth object. The songs are there. All of the data is there. There is an issue with the rules, I've narrowed it down, and the upload works if I set allow true. I know for a fact that it's the rules.

Comment: If the rules reject your write, it's because the state/data don't match with the requirement of the rules. Hence my request to log the exact values that the rules depends on. If you log each of them, either one of them doesn't match - or you've uncovered a bug in the rules engine (which is uncommon, but not impossible).

Comment: Is there a way to log the request object before sending it to firebase? I can easily see if the rules playground mock data matches the data being sent in the request object, but I'm not sure of how to capture that.